# it's insecure to store oauth tokens in cookies?

Tags: cookies, oauth

I'm building an app which doesn't rely on a login system (no database) that will save user's data on dropbox/google drive and others

So when an user open the app he "login" using the cloud service.

Since I'm not going to use any database I was wondering if it's secure to store user oauth token (not the app one) in cookies.

If anyone gets access to cookies he can get access to user data on my app ot it will need also app tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what OAuth version is used and what OAuth flow is used. Generally the OAuth access tokens can be stored only if it can be secured, for example stored in the key chain on iPhone where only application/user granted the access can get it. Same applies to `refresh token` in OAuth2

Comment: oh no they will be stored or in html5 localStorage or in plain cookies in a browser and sometimes (dropbox) it will be used oauth 1. But having a token without the app token and secret will allow access?